# How to deploy Api Rest C# in Virtual Machine Azure

Tags: azure

I have an Api Rest developed with entity framework core 3.1 in C #, I need to deploy the application in a virtual machine in Azure, but it does not work, most of the tutorials that I have taken talk about how to create the virtual machine and publish a web application simple, any guide, help or tutorial?
Generally the error is 500 (internal server error), and problems with the web config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that external requests can land and be processed by the Web Server (typically IIS) running inside the VM. For that you need to open firewall ports to allow inbound traffic within the VM as well as through the network interface (found on the Networking tab) of the VM within the portal.

An API is technically deployed as part of a web application. Hence the following links would help.

- [Link 1](https://medium.com/@rakesh.akalwadi/hosting-net-application-in-azure-vm-using-iis-b266bdd78bc1)
- [Link 2](https://newhelptech.wordpress.com/2017/12/19/step-by-step-how-to-hosting-website-on-azure-vm-using-iis-in-microsoft-azure/) (Note: Video has no voice)

That being said, deploying your API as a App Service in Azure (PaaS) is a much better approach rather than using VMs (unless your API has specific requirements that it needs to be deployed in a VM). App Services also makes setting up other associated services e.g. Logging and monitoring, authentication, etc. much easier.